# JWT ID token without 'name' claim

Tags: android, oauth, google-api, google-play-services

I successfully get an ID token from `GoogleAuthUtil.getToken()` but the Google specific `name` claim is missing.

Worst bit is that at some point in my hacking history, a `name` claim appeared, but I can't reproduce it...

Could this be a scope issue?

I've created a small Android Studio project on GitHub to reproduce this issue: https://github.com/axd1967/idtokentest

thanks

**edit 1:** 
result gives

```
{   "iss": "accounts.google.com",   "sub": "xxxx9706996760", 
"azp":
"xxxx1l3r7a.apps.googleusercontent.com",
"email": "xxx@gmail.com",   "email_verified": true,   "aud":
"xxxx7sc3slj.apps.googleusercontent.com",
"iat": 1435043752,   "exp": 1435047352 }
```

the scopes (see [here](https://github.com/axd1967/idtokentest/blob/ec8a2743e25038aaed492efbf6991c9d0ad3882a/app/src/main/java/axd/be/idtokentest/GoogleSignInActivity.java#L213)) are

`Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN, Scopes.PLUS_ME`

I also added
`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read`

at some point in the hacking frenzy past I got

```
{
  "iss": "accounts.google.com",
  "sub": "xxx39959706996760",
  "azp": "xxxr7a.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "email": "xxxv@gmail.com",
  "email_verified": true,
  "aud": "340233876420-xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "iat": 1434027665,
  "exp": 1434031265,
  "name": "ZoneIT Dev",
  "picture": "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-q849EbIzef0/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAACE/qUzFOcDLA4w/s96-c/photo.jpg",
  "given_name": "ZoneIT",
  "family_name": "Dev"
}
```

**edit 2:** Could it be that these fields cannot be obtained this way (using an ID token)?

**edit 3:** According to [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/CrossClientAuth#androidIdTokens), notice that only `email` is available...